# XWork: How to verify if an action exists or not

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, xwork

I am using weblogic and XWork. I have this error:

```
<Oct 30, 2012 9:06:14 AM GMT> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <ERROR dispatcher.ServletDispatcher - Could not find action
com.opensymphony.xwork.config.ConfigurationException: There is no Action mapped for namespace [XXXXX] and action name [YYY]
```

This used to work fine before an update of the system we use, so it is no trivial error like wrong config in xwork.xml.

I serached all the JARs and I have `[YYY]Servlet.class`. Is that the class for the action? Any other reason because of which the Action can't be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class exists normally the actions should be there. In my case the error was somewhere else.